# How to overcome 502 error while using python requests with proxy

Tags: python-3.x

I can access the below link with `requests`

```
link = https://ceotserms1.telangana.gov.in/MLC/Search.aspx
resp = requests.get(url=link)
```

but when I use a proxy,

```
resp = session.get(url=link,proxies={'https': 'http://ip:port'}) //(it makes no difference if I use https:// in place of http://
```

it throws `502 bad gateway` error. I have tried various proxy IP addresses but in vain.

Is there any way to overcome this? I am able to access the site on the browser using web based proxy though.

Comment: could you please provide the whole code?

Comment: @SumitJaiswal I have edited the question with code